# How to hide input when you click outside of it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have a use case where a user clicks on a search icon, and it display an input.

I want to make it so that when the input is open, anytime you click outside of the input, it hides it.

Of course, I want to keep the toggle I have in place currently as well.

Trying to figure out a solution in vanilla JavaScript, not jQuery.

```js
///////////// Nav - Search Functionality

// Toggle showing and not showing the input

const searchIcon = document.getElementById('search-icon');
const searchInput = document.getElementById('search-input');

searchIcon.addEventListener('click', function() {
  searchInput.classList.toggle('is-active');
  searchInput.classList.toggle('transform-is-active');
});
```

```css
.is-active {
  display: block !important;
}

.is-hidden {
  display: none !important;
}

.transform-is-active {
  width: 200px !important;
}

#search-input {
  display: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

#search-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!--Search-->
<input id="search-input" class="input" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
<img id="search-icon" src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/101791-200.png" alt="Search" tabindex="0" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, i hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```js
///////////// Nav - Search Functionality

// Toggle showing and not showing the input

const searchIcon = document.getElementById('search-icon');
const searchInput = document.getElementById('search-input');

searchIcon.addEventListener('click', function() {
  searchInput.classList.toggle('is-active');
  searchInput.classList.toggle('transform-is-active');
  event.stopPropagation();
});

window.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  if(e.target != document.querySelector('div.a')){
    searchInput.classList.remove('is-active');
  }
});
```

```css
.is-active {
  display: block !important;
}

.is-hidden {
  display: none !important;
}

.transform-is-active {
  width: 200px !important;
}

#search-input {
  display: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
  transition: all 2s ease;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999999;
}
#search-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!--Search-->
<input id="search-input" class="input" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
<img id="search-icon" src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/101791-200.png" alt="Search" tabindex="0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the `blur` event to capture this:

```
const searchIcon = document.getElementById('search-icon');
const searchInput = document.getElementById('search-input');

searchIcon.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  searchInput.classList.toggle('is-active');
  searchInput.classList.toggle('transform-is-active');
  event.stopPropagation();
});

searchInput.addEventListener('blur', function(event) {
  searchInput.classList.remove('is-active');
  searchInput.classList.remove('transform-is-active');
});
```

More details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event

Answer (score 0):

There you go. It hide the input when you click the body (outside the icon) and the toggle is preserved.

```
const searchIcon = document.getElementById('search-icon');
const searchInput = document.getElementById('search-input');

searchInput.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
});

searchIcon.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  searchInput.classList.toggle('is-active');
  searchInput.classList.toggle('transform-is-active');
  event.stopPropagation();
});

document.body.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  searchInput.classList.remove('is-active');
  searchInput.classList.remove('transform-is-active');
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: @Duncan Thacker's answer is a better solution than mine, but you have to click and focus the input before. If you don't do so, the input will not hide when you click outside of it.